# Applet started but not show background color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, background, applet

grateful if someone can help me out for my assignment.
The applet is started and so does the text, but the background color is not there.
Appreciate if someone can help me out. Thank you
My code in Eclipse is as following:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class Applet extends JApplet {

    public void start(){

    }

    public void init(){
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Price is MYR 15.00!", 100, 90);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the color of the `ContentPane` rather than the applet container itself as well as invoking `super.paint(g)` in the `paint` method to paint the container background

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

Note that [custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) in Swing is done by overriding [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) rather than `paint`